# strange loop when logging a user in to my app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

ive created a simple login screen that collects users email. then collects password and encrypts it. then sends that data to firebase database and signs the user in. it changes the textviews and edit texts to say the user is logged in and hides the login button. all works great. that is until i added a new button to log the user back out. for some reason it logs them out but instantly logs the user back in lol. can somebody just take a quick look at the code n see what ive done wrong. thanks.

this is my onClick method

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.btn_login:
            geteditTexts();

            if (SIGNUP) {
              logUserIn();

            } else {
                sendUserDataToFirebase();
            }
             break;

case R.id.btn_logout:
         setStatusLoggedOut();
            break;
```

this method Checks the user exists and that the encrypted password matches the encrypted key stored with in that database then logs the user in

```
private void logUserIn() {
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                 userdata = snapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                 userpassword = snapshot.child("password").getValue(String.class);
                if (userpassword.matches(encryptedMsg) & userdata.matches(memail)) {

                 setStatusLoggedIn(snapshot);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wrong email or password please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No account registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

this method simply sends the data to firebase

```
 private void sendUserDataToFirebase() {
    reference.child("email").setValue(memail);
    reference.child("password").setValue(encryptedMsg);
}
```

i call this method at onStart() to check if the user is logged in or not

```
private void checkUserLogin() {
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

               signedin = snapshot.child("SIGNEDIN").getValue(Boolean.class);
                if (signedin) {
                    setStatusLoggedIn(snapshot);
                }else {
                    setStatusLoggedOut();
                }
            }
```

then finally these 2 methods set the user as logged in or out

```
  private void  setStatusLoggedIn(DataSnapshot snapshot){
        reference.child("SIGNEDIN").setValue(true);
    userdata = snapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
    et_email.setText(userdata);
    userpassword = snapshot.child("password").getValue(String.class);
    DecryptPassword();
    btn_login.setText("Already Signed in");
    btn_login.setOnClickListener(null);
    forgot_password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    signup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    tv_login_desc.setText("You Are Logged In ");
    btn_signout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
private void setStatusLoggedOut(){
    reference.child("SIGNEDIN").setValue(false);
    et_email.setText("");
    et_password.setText("");
    btn_login.setText("Login");
    btn_login.setOnClickListener(this);
    forgot_password.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    signup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    tv_login_desc.setText("Login");
    btn_signout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

everything works ok when logging user in its

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `reference` variable in all the code snippets you shared points to the same database path, then the loop can be explained.

First up, you are adding a permanent listener on `reference` here:

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    ...
```

Then when that listener is trigger, you call `setStatusLoggedIn` which then writes to `reference`:

```
reference.child("SIGNEDIN").setValue(true);
```

This will then trigger the value event listener from the first snippet again, which will then once again write to the database, which triggers the listener again, etc...

If you only want to read from the database once, use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` or `getData` as shown in the documentation on [reading data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once).

Comment: that's exactly whats happened thanks Frank